# Did the preferences from Clive Palmers United Australia Party allow the liberals to win the 2019 federal election

Tags: australia

Clive Palmer did not win one seat for his 80m campaign but did the preferences deal with the liberals result in the liberals winning the overall election.

E.g. for the electorates where liberals won how many of them were close enough for the preferences from UAP to change the result?

Comment: According to ABC News and Financial Review this had a quite an effect, especially when talking about marginal seats. The extent to which this is the case I'm not sure. 21 of the 30 Queensland seats were won by the Coalition.  I assume this doesn't just go for Queensland though. I've counted about 8 seats where Labor lost with a vote of 48% or higher, but there are probably more. Let's say preference issue cost Labor 5 seats, with the result at 75-66 as it stands now, you would end up with a result of 70-71 in Labor's favor.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[Queensland is where there was any net shift in seats](https://tallyroom.aec.gov.au/HouseIncumbentTrailing-24310.htm).

If you look at the [2019 lower house seat results in Queensland](https://tallyroom.aec.gov.au/HouseFirstPrefsTppByDivision-24310-QLD.htm), the seat the coalition won with the smallest winning margin was won by a margin greater than the primary vote for the UAP; If every single UAP voter preferenced Labor over the LNP, they still would have won that seat.

Not a lot to show for a [$55m spend](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-05-21/clive-palmer-55m-federal-election-ad-spend/11135636).

Comment: Also there was a +2 swing in Tasmania to the Liberals.